# output my object as in css structure

Tags: javascript, css

I have a procedure that create/update this object:

```
style={
    "p2":{
        'color':'#fff',
        'background':'red'

    },
    "p3":{
        'color':'#fff',
        'background':'red'

    },
    "h2":{
        'color':'#fff',
        'background':'red'

    }
}
```

How can I output this object for display in css structure to be able to copy and paste it into css file?

Comment: Why is your CSS an object to begin with?

Comment: Maybe [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_space_argument) making use of the `space` parameter, though it's a little unclear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JamesThorpe that leaves some commas to change to semicolon, some colons and quotes to remove, etc.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Yeah that's true.  As I said, a bit unclear :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster Puzzled as to why this is "too broad", and why two votes sufficed to close. Was this marked as "too broad" in the sense it is sometimes used on questions asking for code with no effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate through the object's keys and output it somewhere:

```
var output = "";
for (var key in style) {
    if (style.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        output += key + " { \n";
        for (var prop in style[key]) {
            if (style[key].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                output += prop + ": " + style[key][prop] + ";\n";
            }
        }
        output += "}\n";
    }
}
console.log(output);
document.write(output);

// Not sure if below works
var styleEl = document.createElement("style");
styleEl.innerHTML = output;
document.body.appendChild(styleEl);
```

[Here](https://jsbin.com/bamilaxexu/edit?html,js,console,output) is a JSBin.

Comment: @shlomy, no problem. If this answered the question, feel free to mark it as such.